# Extracting part of a 2D image in OpenCV

Tags: python-3.5, opencv3.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATs1e.jpg)

My goal is to take the image above and "open" it along the center so that the 9 black doublets are in a straight line rather than in a circle. I have tried using the cv2.toPolar() function in OpenCV but the image is quite distorted, as can be seen below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDg7i.png)

I am attempting to try a different approach now. From the center, I would like to access each of the doublet individually, like a pizza slice, and place them side by side

Initially I was thinking of slicing each doublet using two lines from the center of the image to the mid point between the doublets on either side.

My question is: how can I draw contours from the center of the image to the edge of the image, passing through the mid point between any two doublet. If I can draw one, I know that the angle between any two such consecutive contour is 40 degrees.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I noted a few problems here:

1. The toPolar() conversion might have been around the center of the image file, but it is not the center of the object. This causes part of the distortion. If you share your code, I could try playing with the code and improving it.

2.The object is somewhat elliptical, not circular. This means you will still have a wave after correcting the above problem.

3. If you don't mind a semi-automatic solution, you could use OpenCV mouse events to specify the first line and let the program use the 40 degree angle to calculate the rest.

Comment: Many thanks for the response!

https://github.com/AnanDvd/Python-OpenCV/blob/master/cilia2D_topolar_maxRadius.py

Link to image: http://cytochemistry.net/_Media/cilia7_med_hr.jpeg

I also had the doubt that it is finding the center of the image and not the object, that is why I tried finding the center by using contourArea().